# block offensive words, block links etc in mysql insert query?

Tags: php, html, mysql

hi im running a mysql insert query, the idea is users can submit reviews to users profiles, but i wanted to know if there was a way i could block offensive words, links and prevent a way of people spamming it with blog links etc.

would i use a php if statement that says ignore these keywords; "f*ck" etc, i feel the only problem with something like this is i would have to have every word covered in the ignore statement,

or would i include something in my mysql, either way i want to block all links being inserted into the form,

can somone give me some guidance and show me how i woudld do this please thanks

html:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<textarea name="review_recipient" id="review_recipient" maxlength="180" cols="33" rows="5" style=""></textarea><label style="">Who is the Review from?</label>
<br/>
<textarea name="review_content" id="review_content" maxlength="180" cols="33" rows="5" style=""></textarea>
<label style="">Say Something...</label>

<input name="add_review" type="image" src="http://www.playtimeboys.com/assets/img/icons/save-edit.png" BORDER="0" ALT="SUBMIT!"class="review_submit4" /></form>
```

php/mysql:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
     <?php 
    // check if the review form has been sent
    if(isset($_POST['review_content']))
    {
        $content = $_POST['review_content'];
            //We remove slashes depending on the configuration
            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            {
                    $content = stripslashes($content);
            }
            //We check if all the fields are filled
            if($_POST['review_content']!='')
            {


                {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_reviews (id, from_user_id, to_user_id, content) VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$profile_id."', '".$content."');";
                mysql_query($sql, $connection);

                $_SESSION['message']="<div class=\"infobox-wallpost\"><strong>Thank You</strong> - Your review has been sent and is awaiting approval.</div><div class=\"infobox-close4\"></div>"; 
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");

    } } } } ?>
```

Comment: Obligatory: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

Comment: Also, you have a SQL injection vulnerability in your code.  So people inserting bad words into your database is the least of your concerns at this point.  Please: 1) Stop using `mysql_*` and *at least* update to `mysqli_*`, perhaps even us something like PDO; 2) Don't directly concatenate user input into SQL commands, use prepared/parameterized statements instead; 3) Always validate and sanitize user input before doing *anything* with it.

Comment: You can't prevent it, you can only try to reduce it, think of foreign words, character substitutions, multibyte chars etc. If someone really wants to swear then they will find a way to do it.

Comment: Well, obviously you *can* prevent it. You could provide a library of acceptable words or phrases. The drawback of this is that it would obviously be very limiting and frustrating and may cause some users to make remarks as follows: ;-)

Comment: This kind of thing is generally better dealt with by human moderators. Automatic filters have a tendency to cause false-positives; ie blocking things that they shouldn't, which will upset your users. It is also always very easy for someone who really wants to be rude to get around a filter, so if you're worried about this sort of thing you do have to moderate the site manually even if you have a filter in place.

Answer (score 1):

```
$blocked_words="test1,test2,test3,test4";//list of offensive word
$review_from_user ="Your reviews test2 is following hello test1"; //review from user 


$blocked_words_expo = explode(",", $blocked_words);  

foreach($blocked_words_expo as $rmv)
{
    if(strpos($review_from_user,$rmv)==true)
    {
        $review_from_user = str_replace($rmv,'',$review_from_user); 
    }
}
echo $review_from_user;

//and then insert $review_from_user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the values from the bad words table .something like below

```
$blocked_words=array();
$q="select words from block";
$rs=mysql_query($q);
while($rd=mysql_fetch_object($rs))
{
$blocked_words[]=$rd->words;
}
$string_words=explode(" ", $_POST['review_content']);  
$result = array_intersect($blocked_words, $string_words);
```

By the above code you will get all words from table 'block' into $blocked_words.You might need to change with respect to your needs

Comment: Just watch out for Clbuttic mistakes ;)